# Customize Liquid Componets ComboBox colors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using ComboBox from [Liquid Components](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=137) and I would like to customize the colors that appear as background for the items.  I can see that the component has different colors but I can't tell how I can switch between colors using actions script. 
[image]

Comment: I've not used LiquidComponents however in grabbing the download and just checking it out really quickly it appears there's a skins folder that has images in it that appear to match the shot you've posted here, my guess is that those assets need to be edited using an image editor.  From what it says on the site too it appears they mostly stuck with images for skinning but claims you can swap skins at run-time easily http://www.bytearray.org/?p=109

Comment: Correct, and I would like to use colors that are already in the skin that is included. Right now a selected item is dark blue and I would like to set it to a lighter blue which is already included in the skin that is in the project. So I don't want to switch the that asset file but use what is already there.